# Bluetooth PCB inverted F antenna design

Tags: rf, antenna, bluetooth, pcb-antenna

I've been trying to design an omnidirectional PCB inverted-F antenna for a bluetooth project. The aim with the design is to ensure the best range possible with the space I have; Ideally an average gain of >1dBi.  I've come up with a design that I think may work, but I really am struggling to verify if it will perform as required.

Here is the design layout (the tail connects to ground, just doesn't look like it here)
[image]

I know antenna design is not a trivial task, but will this antenna work? if not, what might need modifying to make it perform?

Are there any alternative antennas out there that may fit my performance and spatial requirements? I looked at a TI IFA design but it's just slightly too large for the ~34mm x 5.5mm I have available.

Comment: One small advice: I think You should move the via which is between tail and feeder path slightly to the left, this should improve current path from tail to Rt0.

Comment: Yeah, I've still to finalise the via stitching, but thanks for the tip!

Answer (score 1):

The dimensions look about right to me, assuming your circuit board has an e_r on the order of 4?  It's always best to simulate if possible though!!!

You obviously can't get +1dBi in every direction, but you can probably get that radially from the dipole (17.9 mm x 2 mm) part anywhere but back towards the PCB.

Answer (score 0):

You can refer this post also on inverted-F antenna design and simulation for smart phone PCB

https://anilkrpandey.wordpress.com/2017/01/19/inverted-f-bluetooth-antenna-design-for-smart-phone/